# Not able to select hidden element from drop down list in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

**Html Code:**

```
<select class="select2 ddl visible select2-hidden-accessible" data-allow-clear="true" id="Step1Model_CampaignAdditionalDataTypeId" multiple="" name="Step1Model.CampaignAdditionalDataTypeId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="1">Optus AC Number</option>
<option value="2">Date Of Birth</option>
<option value="3">Pass Phrase</option>
<option value="4">Transaction Id</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above" dir="ltr" style="width: 121.047px;">
<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
<li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
</ul>
</span></span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
</span></span>
```

**I'm using following code(POM) in Selenium Webdriver(with java) to select:**

```
public static By campAddDataType= By.id("Step1Model_CampaignAdditionalDataTypeId");
waitTime = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
waitTime.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(CommonOR.campAddDataType)));
String js = "arguments[0].hidden='false'"; 

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js,(driver.findElement(CommonOR.campAddDataType)));

CampAdd = new Select(driver.findElement(CommonOR.campAddDataType));
CampAdd.selectByVisibleText("Date Of Birth");
```

This drop-down list appears when user mark one option to true. So I believe that's why --> aria-hidden="true" 
And for this option to make false, I ran java script executor but still the required element doesn't get selected from drop-down list.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Essentially you have to use XPath. This has been answered already. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16257/how-to-select-hidden-dropdown-list-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Still the same results come. As per my understanding,some javascriptexecutor code needs to be executed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below.

```
listItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Step1Model_CampaignAdditionalDataTypeId']/option[.='Date Of Birth']"))
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",listItem);
```